# document.getElementByID().load("xml") not working in IE 9+

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am refreshing the look and feel of a legacy app written in classic asp and javascript. I have been using Bootstrap for all my styling and it works fine on most pages but on one of the pages the form data will not persist when the page is refreshed when run as IE 9+ but it does work on versions lower than IE9.

So far I'm thinking it is because pre-IE9 addEventListener isn't supported. Other than going through all of the JQuery code to change `addEventListener` to `attachEvent` is there a way to fix this?

Also, I have tried using jquery versions 1.12.4 and 2.2.3.

Here is a snippet of the code used:

```
<script>
  function Retain_Form_State() {
     document.getElementById("SavedFormData").load("oXMLBranch");
     for (x=23;x<100;x++) {
       var PersistedValue=document.getElementById("SavedFormData").getAttribute(formelements[x]);
       var objPersist=document.getElementById(formelements[x]);
       if (PersistedValue!="" && PersistedValue!=null) {
            objPersist.value=PersistedValue;
         }
      }
  }  
</script>
<DIV class="storeuserData" ID="SavedFormData"></DIV>
```

There is also the following error in the F12 dev tools:

```
Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

Comment: Make sure jQuery is above bootstrap in your HTML. There is no compatibility issue with jQuery's `on` method.

Answer (score 1):

`load()` is not a standard DOM method. It doesn't appear on HTML element objects.

There is a [`load` method in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/load/), but:

- Bootstrap's error message indicates you've failed to load jQuery
- You would need to use the `jQuery(some_selector)` function instead of `document.getElementById`

Comment: I have `<script src="~/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script><script src="~/bootstrap.js"></script>` . So replace the `document.getElementById()` with `jQuery(selector).load()`? I'll try that.

Comment: the jquery reference was wrong but I have fixed it and now have no errors in dev tools but it still isn't persisting the data for me. I replaced `document.getElementById("SavedFormData").load("oXMLBranch")` with `jQuery("SavedFormData").load("oXMLBranch");`